# maintaining couple actions in react - loading screen

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, loading

In my app component I am fetching couple things so there's couple actions. It's a  state component. When one of the actions ends *`isLoading`* property changes to false and screen loading disappears. But it doesn't work properly because one action can take longer than another. How Can I change my `isLoading` property to false after all `async` actions are done?

My code looks something like

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.fetchA();
  this.props.fetchB();
  this.props.fetchC().then(() => {
    this.setState({isLoading: false})
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can chain those promises like this

```
componentDidMount() {
   this.setState({ isLoading: true}); // start your loader

   this.props.fetchA()
   .then(() => {
     return this.props.fetchB();
   })
   .then(() => {
     return this.props.fetchC()
   })
   .then(() => {
     this.setState({ isLoading: false }); // Once done, set loader to false
   })
   .catch(error => {
     console.log('Oh no, something went wrong', error);
   });
}
```

or using async/await with try catch do something fancy like this.

```
constructor () {
   super();
   this.state = {
     isLoading: false,
   };
   this.onLoadData = this.onLoadData.bind(this); // see what I did here, i binded it with "this"
}

componentDidMount() {
   this.onLoadData(); // Call you async method here
}

async onLoadData () {
   this.setState({ isLoading: true}); // start your loader
   try {
     const awaitA = await this.props.fetchA();
     const awaitB = await this.props.fetchB();
     const awaitC = await this.props.fetchC();
     this.setState({ isLoading: false }); // Once done, set loader to false
   } catch (e) {
     console.log('Oh no, something went wrong', error);
   }
}
```

Comment: If this helps you, kindly upvote this answer and mark this as your answer. Also I added an approach where you could do this with async/await if you want.

Comment: Idea with async is much cleaner and nicer! BTW: I dont think u can use setState method outside of constructor even if 'this' is binded - I'm talking about the first initialization.

Comment: You directly set state in constructor using `this.state={}` and you can set state anywhere in your code using `this.setState({ })` anywhere in your code except render method. All you need is to bind `this` to it's right context for this to work.

Comment: Wasn't working for me. Says isLoading property is null. Had to put it back in constuctor. Im aware it should work cause' this' has component context but.. weird stuff..

Comment: Oh that, yes you have to initialize that in the constructor. I forgot. Sorry. I updated my answer. Apologize. Check the constructor() method now.